# pywinauto: дружит ли с многопоточностью?

Tags: pywinauto

Приложение, управляемое pywinauto, позволяет создавать несколько экземпляров одного окна одновременно. Окна отличаются по заголовку, поэтому проблем с идентификацией каждого отдельного окна не будет. Станет ли корректно работать pywinauto, если управление каждым отдельным окном будет вынесено в отдельный тред?

Comment: Уточнение. Все элементы конкретного главного окна являются дочерними по отношению к этому главному окну, как показывает лог метода dump_tree. Главных окон можно создать сразу несколько, с разными заголовками.

Comment: Можно-то оно можно, только окна фокус будут перебивать друг у друга, что может помешать работе каждого отдельного потока. Если используются методы типа `.click_input()` и `.type_keys()`, то практически гарантированно огребёте кучу проблем. Если использовать методы, не требующие фокуса, то может быть что-то получится. Это сложный путь экспериментов. Например, в "win32" бэкенде есть методы `.send_chars()` и `.send_keystrokes()`, которые для каких-то текстовых полей работают, для каких-то нет. Это и от приложения тоже зависит.

Comment: По-моему, для `backend="uia"` нужно ещё `sys.coinit_flags = 2` указывать перед импортом pywinauto, это для инициализации COM объектов в UIAutomationCore.dll в случае нескольких потоков. Но это несложно. Конкуренция за фокус - это главная проблема, как мне кажется.